# numberOfLines not working

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

This is my code, and not working the numberOfLines.
How can i fix it.

```
let texts = UILabel()
texts.frame.size.width = 100
texts.text = "fehjafiuehfoaijeoijaoifjajfeiojfoiafeafelfhlkfesjahflkejshflesjfheakjfehlfkjehalkfh"
texts.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
texts.numberOfLines = 2
texts.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .light)
texts.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
let DetailSpaceStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
DetailSpaceStyle.lineSpacing = 6.0
let detailSpaceAttr = [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: DetailSpaceStyle]
texts.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: texts.text!, attributes: detailSpaceAttr)
texts.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: what is this doing and what is your expected result?, if you don't give us that info is almost impossible to help you

Comment: Please check your texts height

Comment: Use `numberOfLines = 0`

Comment: sorry, i already added height. Basically this code is displayed clearly. But  not show the "..." on last words.

Comment: just edit this line `let texts = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the "..." on last words you should use

`texts.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail` **instead** of `texts.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping`

and this only will appear if the length of the text exceeds the space of two lines that you are providing for it

Comment: Thankyou i solved with this :)  i need put that end add linebreakmode and numberoflines before sizetofit method.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify `UILabel` height

`texts.frame.size.height = 100`

and also you need to set `CGRect` to `UILabel` as told by `@Anbu.karthik`

```
    let texts = UILabel()
    texts.frame.origin.x = 5
    texts.frame.origin.y = 5
    texts.frame.size.width = 100
    texts.frame.size.height = 100
    texts.text = "fehjafiuehfoaijeoijaoifjajfeiojfoiafeafelfhlkfesjahflkejshflesjfheakjfehlfkjehalkfh"
    texts.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    texts.numberOfLines = 2
    texts.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .light)
    texts.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    let DetailSpaceStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    DetailSpaceStyle.lineSpacing = 6.0
    let detailSpaceAttr = [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: DetailSpaceStyle]
    texts.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: texts.text!, attributes: detailSpaceAttr)
    texts.sizeToFit()
    self.view.addSubview(texts)
```

Comment: in fact in the code provided by the OP, is not adding the Label to the UI